# python count keywords in a python file without counting inside quotation marks

Tags: python

For example:

```
import codecs

def main():
    fileName = input("Please input a python file: ")
    file = codecs.open(fileName, encoding = "utf8")
    fornum = 0
    for line in file:
        data = line.split()
        if "for" in data:
            fornum += 1
    print("The number of for loop in", fileName, ":", fornum)

main()
```

There are 1 for-statement in above codes. But the program counts the 'for' inside the quotation mark which is not expected and it displays 2. How can I change the codes to make it counts the keywords(for) without counting the words inside ""? Thx

Comment: What if the line is `# comment about a for loop` - that will count even though it's not a loop.

Comment: And what if it's a for loop in an eval statement ?  :)

Comment: You have to actually parse the python code to do this properly.

Comment: nice.... a lot of problem to fix..

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments to propely count for loops you should parse Python file and walk through it AST. You could do it with [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module. Example code:

```
import ast

def main():
    fileName = input("Please input a python file: ")
    with open(fileName) as f:
        src = f.read()
        source_tree = ast.parse(src) # get AST of source file
    fornum = 0
    # and recursively walk through all AST nodes
    for n in ast.walk(source_tree):
        if n.__class__.__name__ == "For":
            fornum = fornum+1
    print("The number of for loop in ", fileName, ":", fornum)

main()
```

Comment: the codes work well for "For" but it does not work when I count how many "print" in a file. Any other methods to count the keywords? Thx for help >.<